# Angular - Conditional wrapper block

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a `<div>` that I want to conditionally wrap in a `<a>` as in:

```
<a>
  <div>Stuff that I always want to see</div>
</a>
```

If I use `ng-if` on the `<a>`, it would hide the `<div>` as well. If a certain variable is `false`, I want the `<div>` to just be by itself.

I could use a `<div>` instead of `<a>` and then style it like an `<a>` if the variable is `true` but I was hoping there would be a better way.

Thanks!

Comment: If your intent is just to "disable" the link behavior, you could simply change those things with styles and a click handler. Or make your inner div look and behave like a link only when you want.

Comment: I mentioned that approach in the last sentence of the post. Definitely a valid way of doing it, but I was hoping to see if there would be a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a directive that would use `angular.element.wrap()` depending on boolean

Something like:

```
<div link-wrap="wraplinks" url="http://google.com"></div>
```

JS

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) { 
  $scope.wraplinks = true;
});

app.directive('linkWrap', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      url: '@',
      linkWrap: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, elem) {
      scope.$watch('linkWrap', function(nVal, oVal){
        if(nVal){
           elem.wrap('<a href="' + scope.url +'"></a>')
        }else{
          if(elem.parent()[0].tagName=='A'){
            elem.parent().replaceWith(elem)
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/i4YwsZpNtjuZGkrmg4AC?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: I like this approach, its clean and is easily reusable.